# XTDE0420: Cannot create an attribute node

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have my xml something similar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
    xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
    xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1"
    xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 2.1\maindoc\UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:CustomizationID>2.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ID>FB98-00396</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2018-06-15</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cac:Signature>
        <cbc:ID>FB98-00396</cbc:ID>
        <cac:SignatoryParty>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>20338570041</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>
                    <![CDATA[UBL]]>
                </cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:SignatoryParty>
        <cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
            <cac:ExternalReference>
                <cbc:URI>FB98-00396</cbc:URI>
            </cac:ExternalReference>
        </cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
    </cac:Signature>
</Invoice>
```

And this is my xsl to validate XML above:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
            xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
            xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
version="2.0">
            <xsl:include href="error_utils.xsl" dp:ignore-multiple="yes" />
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:include href="error_utils.xsl" dp:ignore-multiple="yes" />
            <xsl:template match="/*">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                .......//more code here
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template name="existAndRegexpValidateElement">
                <xsl:param name="errorCodeNotExist" />
                <xsl:param name="errorCodeValidate" />
                <xsl:param name="node" />
                <xsl:param name="regexp" />
                <xsl:param name="isError" select="true()"/>
                <xsl:param name="descripcion" select="'Error Expr Regular'"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(string($node))">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$isError">
                                <xsl:call-template name="rejectCall">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="errorCode" select="$errorCodeNotExist" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="errorMessage" select="concat($descripcion,': ', $errorCodeNotExist,' (nodo: &quot;',name($node/parent::*),'/', name($node), '&quot; valor: &quot;', $node, '&quot;)')" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:call-template name="addWarning">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="warningCode" select="$errorCodeNotExist" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="warningMessage" select="concat($descripcion,': ', $errorCodeNotExist,' (nodo: &quot;',name($node/parent::*),'/', name($node), '&quot; valor: &quot;', $node, '&quot;)')" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:if test='not(matches($node,$regexp))'>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$isError">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="rejectCall">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="errorCode" select="$errorCodeValidate" />
                                        <xsl:with-param name="errorMessage" select="concat($descripcion,': ', $errorCodeValidate,' (nodo: &quot;',name($node/parent::*),'/', name($node), '&quot; valor: &quot;', $node, '&quot;)')" />
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="addWarning">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="warningCode" select="$errorCodeValidate" />
                                        <xsl:with-param name="warningMessage" select="concat($descripcion,': ', $errorCodeValidate,' (nodo: &quot;',name($node/parent::*),'/', name($node), '&quot; valor: &quot;', $node, '&quot;)')" />
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I applied validation I got:

```
Error at char 2 in xsl:apply-templates/@select on line ....
  XTDE0420: Cannot create an attribute node (xsi:schemaLocation) whose parent is a document
  node. Most recent element start tag was output at line -1 of module *unknown*
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:///home/.....)
     processing /Invoice/@xsi:schemaLocation
  in built-in template rule
```

It seems to be because of xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 2.1\maindoc\UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd" over identity template:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
```

Because when I delete xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 2.1\maindoc\UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd" from XML it does not have any error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

With the template

```
        <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            .......//more code here
        </xsl:template>
```

you process the root element and transform only its attributes and child nodes, but you don't copy the root element. As your root element has one attribute `xsi:schemaLocation` and the template you have provided for attributes is the identity transformation that attribute is copied to the result tree but that attempt gives you the error as you can't attach any attribute node to a document node, you can only attach it to an element node.

It is not clear what you want to achieve and why you need that template matching `/*`, but if you want to copy the attributes of the root element you need to make sure you copy the root element as well with e.g. `xsl:copy` or you process its attributes after creating a different element node.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I still do not what happened but I decided use xsl 3.0 using <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> instead and it works perfectly.